# Cordova api.ai ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ApiAIPlugin

Tags: cordova, referenceerror, dialogflow-es

Trying to include api.ai, but I getting: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ApiAIPlugin... What to do ?